# External function calls with multiple dependent DLLs

Tags: windows, dll, inno-setup

I want to call a couple APIs from a DLL that has a number of dependent DLLs. I added all the DLLs to the setup package and defined the prototypes:

```
function myapi_Init(): Integer;
external 'myapi_init@A.dll stdcall setuponly loadwithalteredsearchpath delayload';
```

I extract all the DLLs using `ExtractTemporaryFiles('*.dll')` just fine in `InitializeSetup()` and then attempt to call the respective API. I get a runtime error, cannot import dll...

I redefined the prototype as follows and removed the call to extract the DLLs:

```
function myapi_Init(): Integer;
external 'myapi_init@files:A.dll,B.dll,C.dll,D.dll,E.dll stdcall setuponly loadwithalteredsearchpath delayload';
```

This works fine. I checked and in both cases, all the appropriate DLLs are extracted and in the same place. I prefer the first case because it avoids spelling out all the DLL names for each API. What am I doing wrong in the first case to cause failure?

Comment: InnoSetup doesn't have `{tmp}` directory in [`DLL library search path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx), so it fails due to a missing file, I'd say. In other words, you extract the library into the `{tmp}` folder, but Windows doesn't search for it there. Try to use the `files:` way instead. My guess is that if you use `files:` path, the library will be extracted into the `{tmp}` folder anyway. Then might be enough to extract the other (dependent) ones. But it's all my guess (except that `{tmp}` and library search path).

Comment: Doesn't Inno automatically add `{tmp}` to the search path for DLLs? It appears to be in the "path" when referencing other files relatively. Also, the example has a prototype referencing a DLL in the `{app}` directory, so it must modify the DLL search path dynamically... maybe? What good is `loadwithalteredsearchpath` if it doesn't add at least `{tmp}` to the path?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to say that without InnoSetup and its source by hand. But yes, you're right, I realized now that the setup application itself is executed from that temp folder (and the current application path is checked in the DLL search path).